# Sample size from mean() on groupby object

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to record the sample size when calling the `mean()` method of a groupby object?

Consider the following dataframe:

```
In [16]: df
Out[16]:
   formation  phi  sw
0        nio   14  47
1        nio   10  16
2        nio   12  12
3        nio   19  82
4        nio   23  43
5     fthays   24  19
6     codell   23   5
7     codell   24  45
8     codell    9  11
9   graneros   26  11
10  graneros   15  45
11  graneros   12  16
12      dkot   11  79
```

It's easy enough to compute the mean across each of these `formation`s using the `mean()` method of the groupby object:

```
In [17]: df.groupby(['formation']).mean()
Out[17]:
                 phi         sw
formation
codell     18.666667  20.333333
dkot       11.000000  79.000000
fthays     24.000000  19.000000
graneros   17.666667  24.000000
nio        15.600000  40.000000
```

But I'd like to know if there's a way to add a column for the sample size.  So my desired output would be something like:

```
                 phi         sw   n
formation
codell     18.666667  20.333333   3 
dkot       11.000000  79.000000   1
fthays     24.000000  19.000000   1
graneros   17.666667  24.000000   3
nio        15.600000  40.000000   5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by using the [`aggregate`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) function, with the `mean` and `count` functions as arguments.

```
>> df.groupby(['formation']).aggregate([np.mean, np.size])
```

Comment: For some reason, I am getting an error when I use that:  
`TypeError: mean() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)`.  Maybe a version issue? I'm running 0.16.1--  I will try to upgrade and try with 0.16.2

Comment: `df.groupby(['formation']).aggregate([np.mean, np.size])` did the trick

Comment: It should be `.aggregate(['mean', 'count'])` (note the brackets).